# How to animate multiple Path elements in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a collection of glyphs that are in form of WPF `<Path>` elements.

Something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Path Data="..." Height="33.333" Stretch="Fill" Width="33.334"/>
    <Path Data="..." Height="33.333" Stretch="Fill" Width="33.334"/>
    <Path Data="..." Height="33.333" Stretch="Fill" Width="33.334"/>
    <Path Data="..." Height="33.333" Stretch="Fill" Width="33.334"/>
</Grid>
```

These are just image or icon glyphs. I'm trying to find a way to switch or flip between these various Path elements so that it looks like an animation. I'm pretty new to WPF and have tried looking for examples but couldn't find anything similar here or elsewhere on the web. The closest example I found was erasing one `<Image>` element with another using `Storyboard` and `DoubleAnimation` but I can't figure out how to apply it to `<Path>`.

I'm basically trying to find a way to show one path element and hide all other paths, wait a second, show next path element and hide all other, and so on, to make it look like a flip animation.

I would appreciate if someone can post a simple example or point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: What property are you trying to animate? Do you want to animate all the `Path`s at the same time?

Comment: Not sure if this makes sense but I'm basically trying to show one path element and hide all other paths, wait a second, show next path element and hide all other, and so on.

Comment: Makes sense. What is the condition to trigger the animations though?

Comment: Can be any condition. Window.Loaded is good enough for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright give this a try. Note that each `Path` will get its own `Storyboard`. So if you have 4 `Path`s, you get 4 `Storyboard`s.

```
<Path>
    <Path.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                             From="0" 
                                             To="1" 
                                             Duration="00:00:1"
                                             BeginTime="00:00:1" 
                                             AutoReverse="True"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Path.Style>
</Path>
<Path>
    <Path.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                             From="0" To="1" 
                                             Duration="00:00:1" 
                                             BeginTime="00:00:2"
                                             AutoReverse="True"/>

                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Path.Style>
</Path>
<Path>
    <Path.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                             From="0" To="1"
                                             Duration="00:00:1"
                                             BeginTime="00:00:3"
                                             AutoReverse="True"/>

                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Path.Style>
</Path>
<Path>
    <Path.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                             From="0" 
                                             To="1" 
                                             Duration="00:00:1"
                                             BeginTime="00:00:4" 
                                             AutoReverse="True"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Path.Style>
</Path>
```

Notice how we're using the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event to trigger the animation. You can use this event on virtually any UI element. Each storyboard changes the opacity from 0 (invisible) to 1 (completely visible) in 1 second (you can change this using the `Duration` property). Also, the `BeginTime` property is different for each storyboard, this is required to make sure the items are animated one after another. Finally, we set the `AutoReverse` property to make sure the `Path`s are disappeared (i.e. the animation is reversed). This should give you the idea.

Comment: PoweredByOrange, thanks for putting together that little sample. I'm going to mark your post as the answer because it does achieve what I asked for in my question. The `Storyboard` also seems to create a fade in fade out effect, which is pretty cool - I'm good with C# but WPF newbie so still learning. I however have 30 path elements, so I gave up on a XAML solution and decided to show/hide the paths from code-behind. It's not MVVM but it works.

Comment: @user785286 Well if you have a lot of `Path`s you can create a generic `Storyboard` in the code-behind and apply it to all the paths. The tricky part is to figure out a way to add a delay.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange, If I set same BeginTime for all elements, is it guaranteed that all items will be animated in parallel/simultaneously?